# Some questions on toroidal graphs

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

The complete graph $K_4$ is planar, and like every planar graph it is also embeddable into the torus.

a) Why does $K_4$ count as a *triangulation* of the sphere, but not of the torus?

b) What's the name of graphs that are toroidal, but not planar?

c) Is there a criterion for toroidal graphs comparable to [Kuratowski's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski.27s_and_Wagner.27s_theorems) for planar graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An embedding is triangular if each face is a triangle. For the embedding of $K_4$ you have in mind, one face is not bounded by a triangle - the "outside" face.

Note that for surfaces other than the sphere, it is required that each face be homeomorphic to a disc, i.e., the embedding must be *cellular*. The graphs will cellular embeddings in a given surface form a minor-closed class, so by the Roberston-Seymour theorem there is a finite class of forbidden minors and hence we do have a good analog of Kuratowski's theorem. Note though, that finite does not mean small.

Comment: So what is a triangle, then? The outside face - like all the others - has three vertices and three edges. (But it's not "convex".)

Comment: The outside face is a torus with a triangle. It is not homeomorphic to a disc, and so the embedding is not cellular.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, that seems to be what I did not see!

Comment: And I meant to write "torus with a triangle removed", but I guess you worked it out.

Comment: At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem#Obstruction_sets I learn that there are at least 16,000 forbidden minors for toroidal graphs. That's discouraging!

Comment: a side question (too unimportant to ask it as a real question): Does a triangle count as a triangulation of the sphere?

Comment: Yes. Because if you cut along the sides of the triangle, you are left with two triangles.

Answer (score 1):

You want the book [Topological Graph Theory](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486417417.html) by Gross and Tucker.

Note that $K_7$ can be imbedded in the torus, page 137. So, my guess for part (a) is that you cannot draw $K_4$ on the torus in such a way that each edge triple making a triangle in the graph actually bounds a simply connected region on the surface.

(b) called genus one.

(c) not sure. Note complete bipartite $K_{4,4}$ and $K_{3,6}$ are genus one, page 211, Thm 4.5.3, Ringel (1965)